# How do I aggregate shape file polygons in Leaflet R?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shapefile

I am trying to create a simple leaflet map of Victoria to display the name when the suburb is clicked.

Since my shapefile contains more granular data that shows the street level information, I want to aggregate the granular data based on the suburb column in my shapefile so that when the suburb is clicked, it highlights the suburb which is made up of smaller street-level shapes.

My shapefile looks like this

```
MOVEMENT_I,                       DISPLAY_NA, id     
          1, 0 Giddings Street, North Geelong,  0
          6,          Lennoxs Lane, Fiskville,  5
```

I have already created the suburb column in my shapefile dataset which was derived from the display name. I can see the suburb name coming up accurately in popup labels for each smaller shape in suburbs.

```r
locations <- leaflet(destinationsOnly) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng=144.9671 , lat=-37.8183, popup="Flinders Street Railway Station")%>%
  addPolygons(data = PG,color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
            opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.2,popup = PG$suburb,
            highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
                                                bringToFront = TRUE))

locations
```

I hope that there is a way to only highlight the suburb borders in case. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.